# How to setup cocos2D-X for android On Mac?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I made game in cocos2d in xcode for iPhone. Now i want to make game for android in cocos2d-x but not getting any clear steps how to install cocos2d-x and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be working on windows and making an android game you need to first download cocos2dx from this link - http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download
then you have to download few more things like python, android ndk version 9 or 10, apache ant and android sdk.

after getting all this set the path in environment variable
ex:
This one is for the manual process:

1. ANDROID_SDK_ROOT - C:\Cocos\Android SDK\sdk
2. ANT_ROOT - D:\Cocos_Setup\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin
3. COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT - D:\Cocos_Setup\Cocos2d-x\cocos2d-x-3.10\tools\cocos2d-console\bin
4. COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT - D:\Cocos_Setup\Cocos2d-x\cocos2d-x-3.10\templates
5. COCOS_X_ROOT - D:\Cocos_Setup\Cocos2d-x
6. NDK_ROOT - D:\Cocos_Setup\android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r10e
   Or
   You can directly extract the downloaded cocos2dx zip the open it and and run "setup.py"
   It will ask to set the environment variable. Do it as it asks.
   Thats it.
   Run your first demo project.

If not able to understand it properly the you can follow this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqtT0E68TJM